# Using dynamically updated data attribute in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use a dynamically updated data attribute with jQuery.

When I first click the button the clientPrefID grabs the correct data. In my ajax call, I return the next preference id and I update the data in the success function so that I can do the same thing with a different set of data. When I inspect element on the page I can see that the the data-client-pref-id correctly updates. However, when I click the button next, the clientPrefID is still the old value! See below that I alert the value to check that this is the issue.

Here is the javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.pref-btn', function(e) {
    var clientPrefID = $(this).data('client-pref-id');
    var score = $(this).data('score');

    // see if clientPrefID is correct value 
    alert(clientPrefID);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/portal/includes/ajax_portal.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            theAction: "updatePreferenceScore",
            clientPrefID: clientPrefID,
            score: score
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.error == undefined) {
                //if the data did not return errors,
                //update the item name and image and preference id
                $('#item-name').html(data.plu_commodity_name);
                $('#item-img').html("<img src=\"../images/item_images/plu_items/" + data.ifps_image_source + "\" height='100px'>");
                $('.pref-btn').each(function() {
                    $(this).attr("data-client-pref-id", data.client_pref_id);
                });
            } else {
                console.log(data.error)
            }
        }
    })
});
```

And here is the html

```
<div class="row my-3 text-center">
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card mx-2 py-3 pref-btn pointer" data-score="2" data-client-pref-id="<?php echo $next_pref_plu['client_pref_id']; ?>">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>NO</h5>
                <img src="../images/x.png" height="75px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card mx-2" style="border:none">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 id="item-name"><?php echo $next_pref_plu['plu_commodity_name']; ?></h4>
                <div id="item-img"><img src="../images/item_images/plu_items/<?php echo $next_pref_plu['ifps_image_source']; ?>" height="100px"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card mx-2 py-3 pref-btn pointer" data-score="1" data-client-pref-id="<?php echo $next_pref_plu['client_pref_id']; ?>">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>YES</h5>
                <img src="../images/check.png" height="75px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Rae - welcome to SO. Glad you found an answer to your question. Now, please click the checkmark beside the answer below to select it as correct - to both reward the answer and to close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the data attribute use :

```
$(this).data("client-pref-id", data.client_pref_id);
```

instead of

```
$(this).attr("data-client-pref-id", data.client_pref_id);
```

If I recall correctly, the new value won't display in the inspector but it will be kept jQuery's memory.

As a side note, if you're using `$(this)` more than once, it's faster to store it in a variable.

Something like this.

```
var t = $(this);

var clientPrefID = t.data('client-pref-id');
var score = t.data('score');
```

Comment: Thank you , this fixed it! I had used the first syntax previously but because it wasn't updating in the inspector I thought it wasn't working. Good to know.